# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, cleardb

i have a problem when trying to connect to a cleardb database it gives me this error.

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

i check my connection information and it's correct because i test it in navicat and it connect successfully.
Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that laravel not taking new connection info so i restart the server and it's working.